# Movilizer - retrieve current platform

Tags: mobile, movilizer

How can I get the information which device the end user is using atm?
It would be enough for me to know whether the user is using iOS, Android, etc.
I've created a Movelet for testing purposes which connects and reads from a useragent api. But it does not return the expected information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right MEL method for that task would be

```
numeric getClientType()
```

Return values are numeric codes that indicate the platform. To list some of them (rest can be found in the documentation):

- 11 Android
- 20 WinMobile CF 2.0
- 21 WinMobile CF 3.5
- 22 WinPhone 8.0
- 31 Desktop standard
- 32 Desktop standard FX
- 33 Desktop standard native
- 50 BlackBerry